# jetty, servlet 3.0, spring host header attack prevention

Tags: java, spring, jetty, servlet-3.0, dropwizard

There is a known attack type called host header attack scripting. It is basically changing the "**X-Forwarded-Host**" header and all calls you make by doing:

```
String serverName = reqest.getServerName();
```

results in making serverName is exactly the X-Forwarded-Host header value. Hence all the operations based on `serverName` variable are left untrusty. If you are embedding url's to your web sites like doing:

```
<a href="http://<%=request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()%>">Some link</a>
```

You might be referring another location.

Is there another method to retrieve server name correctly inspite of a malicious X-Forwarded-Host header?

All these are overcome with only giving relative urls instead of full urls. The case i face now consists embedding some full urls from https to http, therefore i cannot use relative urls.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can disable forwarded feature. This can be done within **AbstractConnector**, there is a method called **setForwarded**.

Meanwhile, this is very simple if you are using dropwizard, just edit your yml file and change **useForwardedHeaders** field in http config. (in 0.6.2)